# How does Ionic know which state to select?

Tags: ionic-framework, routes

I have the following code from a tutorial:
`index.hmtl`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   ...
  </head>
  <body ng-app="App">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app.js`:

```
angular.module('App', ['ionic'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html'
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
...
})
```

The application works fine. But my question is how does the application know, that it has to show the `home` view? Is it because it is the only state defined? I cannot see in anywhere in the code that says "ok get the `home` view!" I only have defined the state, but cant see what calls it...

If I change the name of the state to `home2`, it still finds the template. But if I change the value of `url` to `/home2`, it does not finde the template anymore. So it a default setting of ionic, that there must exist a state with the url `/home`?

Comment: this line `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');` means if nothing is defined show `home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');` means if a route is requested, that is something other than the routes defined, show `/home`.